Equivalent condition for Lindeberg-Levy-Feller Central Limit Theorem.

Let $\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables. Let
$$
S_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} X_{j}, \quad s_{n}^{2}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbb E\left(X_{j}^{2}\right)<\infty
$$
If $s_{n}^{2} \rightarrow \infty,$ then show that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} s_{n}^{-2} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbb E\left\{X_{j}^{2} \mathbf 1\left ({\left|X_{j}\right|>\varepsilon s_{n}}\right ) \right \}=0 \text { for all } \varepsilon>0 \\ \Longleftrightarrow \quad
& \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} s_{n}^{-2} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbb E\left \{X_{j}^{2} \mathbf 1 \left ({\left|X_{j}\right|>\varepsilon s_{j}}\right ) \right \}=0 \text { for all } \varepsilon>0.
\end{aligned}
$$

The direction '$\Longleftarrow$'  is obvious since $s_n > s_j$ for all $1 \leq j \leq n.$ How to show the reverse direction? Any small suggestion would be welcomed.
Regards
Anil.
